# Atom-Editor Error - how to solve?

Tags: atom-editor

As soon as I start Atom and try to write Python Code, i get this warning message with every entry:

```
Provided path doesn't exist.
pylama
Please fix pylama path or install latest version
```

Uninstall / reinstall of pylama (also Atom) does not help... what can I do?

Comment: What Platform are you on? Is pylama installed(correctly)? Which package raises the error?

Comment: I use Xubuntu Linux.

I don´t know if pylama is installed correctly => how can I tell?

I don´t know which package raises the error => how can I tell?

Comment: open a terminal: try `pylama -v`, if it fails try `sudo apt-get install pylama` if it can't find a package with that name lookup online how to install pylama. As far as which package raises the error, it should say somehwere in the box that the error brings up

Comment: Did you install any packages for Atom that are designed for python? maybe `language-python` or `linter-python` or something like that? My guess would be that a package that you installed is looking for pylama and cannot find it. But we can't tell you how to fix it uless we know exactly where the error is coming from

Comment: thx Alex. It was not installed. Installation was possible by "pip install pylama" via terminal. And just as you thought I had packages that were looking for pylama to work properly.
thx!

Comment: It worked for me to specify the absolute executable path ( /usr/local/bin/pylama and not pylama only) in Packages / Linter Python settings.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to the error information disappear,you just open the aom settings,find the installed linter package,cancel the option as follow

lint on change ,don't select this option.